# readdir() doesn't work properly for subdirectories

Tags: c, readdir

I have this function that uses readdir(). I use stat() to get info about the files that are in the directory I give as parameter.

> folder_name[] is actually the absolute path for the directory I want to read

The function works fine for names like `.` or `./lfac` but it doesn't work properly for names like `./lfac/comp`. I test it and it reads some files from that directory but not all of them. The executable file is placed in the root directory.

I have another function (recursive function) which also uses readdir() and stores a list with the absolute paths of the files that are in the directory (I give as parameter) and its subdirectories. This function has the same problem.

```
void content(char folder_name[], char *answer)
{                               
    DIR *diropen;
    struct dirent *dirread;

    if ((diropen = opendir(folder_name)) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error opening directory %s\n",folder_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((dirread = readdir (diropen)) != NULL)
    {
        struct stat sb;
        memset(&sb, 0, sizeof sb);
        char *temp;
        temp = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
        temp[0] = 0;
        sprintf(temp,"%s/%s",folder_name,dirread->d_name);
        if(strcmp(dirread->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(dirread->d_name,".")==0)
            continue;
        if (stat(temp, &sb) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        strcat(answer,"File name:                ");
        strcat(answer,dirread->d_name);
        strcat(answer,"\n");
        strcat(answer,"File type:                ");
        switch (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
        case S_IFBLK:  strcat(answer,"block device\n");            break;
        case S_IFCHR:  strcat(answer,"character device\n");        break;
        case S_IFDIR:  strcat(answer,"directory\n");               break;
        case S_IFIFO:  strcat(answer,"FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
        case S_IFLNK:  strcat(answer,"symlink\n");                 break;
        case S_IFREG:  strcat(answer,"regular file\n");            break;
        case S_IFSOCK: strcat(answer,"socket\n");                  break;
        default:       strcat(answer,"unknown?\n");                break;
        }
        sprintf(temp,"I-node number:            %ld\n", (long) sb.st_ino); strcat(answer,temp);
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this code, and see if it helps you: http://pastebin.com/YEvMnVWB 
it removes folders recursively

Comment: if(strcmp(dirread->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(dirread->d_name,".")==0) this should check for "." and ".."

Comment: Also on xfs st_mode is not filled in correctly, so you might need to call stat if you need "universal" approach.

Comment: What do you exactly means by "it doesn't work properly for names like ./lfac/comp"? Your code don't recurse into subdirs so it cannot display subdirs contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trampling with heavy boots through your computer's memory, so you get Undefined Behavior.

This part

```
char *temp;
temp = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
temp[0] = 0;
sprintf(temp,"%s/%s",folder_name,dirread->d_name);
```

allocates just 1 byte of memory, per `sizeof(char)`, but the very next thing you do is writing *way* longer strings into it.

You need to allocate more than that -- at least as much as the length of your folder path, plus the separator, plus the maximally allowed file name length. There are a few constants such as `MAX_FILE_PATH` you could use, but these are compiler and system dependent; I usually use something "surely large enough, cough cough" such as `1024`.

It's not really clear to me why you *allocate* that memory in the loop, though. (Mainly because you don't free it anywhere, so I don't know the intended scope.) You can do this before your loop, and then you might as well use

```
char temp[1024];
```

instead of dynamic allocation.

Comment: I finally found the problem! The function wasn't the problem. I dynamically allocated the variable answer in a wrong way "(char*) malloc (sizeof(char));" and I allocated more space and now it works for all situations.